# Electron Webpack Vue global variables

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, electron

I'm trying for hours now to get global variables to work in electron with webpack and vue, but vue can't find the declared variable.

webpack.config.js

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
      "vue-style-loader",
      "css-loader",
      {
        loader: "sass-resources-loader",
        options: {
          resources: 'src/assets/scss/custom/_variables.scss'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

App.vue

```
background-color: $gray;
```

error:

```
background-color: $gray-900;
                     ^
        Undefined variable: "$gray-900".
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be the `resources` path being not correctly resolved from the root directory, hence they're never really defined.

#### Possible solution

Assuming your `webpack.config.js` file is in the same directory as the `src/`:

```js
{
  loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
  options: {
    resources: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/scss/custom/_variables.scss')
  },
}
```